# DPC_Watchdog_Violation when ever I try running my code

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

After a minute of running that code i get the DPC_Watchdog_Violation error, I made sure I had the right chrome version for chrome-driver, I also tried a different chrome version that goes with chrome driver but still same error.

Comment: haven't seen a bluescreen for a while!  Usually those indicate hardware or driver issues.  Are there any other times when this happens?  (when you're not using selenium?)

Comment: no it only happens when i'm using selenium, i will try to find another framework similar to selenium and see if that makes any difference

Comment: You are not the only one with this issue. I have the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the selenium with Firefox + geckodriver combination. It worked for me and didn't crash a single time. Seems that chromedriver has a bug in it or something.
Here are some useful links to getting the correct driver version:
[Correct driver version table](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)
[Driver downloads](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
Selenium also has an IDE which has very useful functions like action recordings. I highly recommend it as you can export python files from it and then use the generated commands without having to find all of the ids/classes.